# How would I give CSS property to a cloned element as Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

I'm trying to give `translateX()` property to cloned element which is called `this.firstClone` as javascript. The problem is `this.firstClone` doesn't refer to the cloned element even the value itself makes the clone in the code.

```
constructor($el) {
  this.$el = $el; // 0
  this.myCards = this.$el.find('a'); // 1
  this.myCount = 1; // 2
  this.myLength = this.myCards.length; // 3
  this.firstClone = this.myCards.first().before(this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned')); // 4 this makes the clone.
  this.lastClone = this.myCards.last().after(this.myCards.first().clone().addClass('cloned'));
}
```

Above there, `this.firstClone` makes the clone of the last image to the first in the set. And also when I remove that, the cloned element is gone. There's no problem to make, set or remove the cloned image.

But when I `console.log` it, it refers second element which has `translateX(1%)` in DOM. The property is also going to set to the second element when I do like this: `this.firstClone.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-1) + "%)";`

Is this a glitch of javascript? or do I just misunderstanding about `.first()` and `.clone()` method?

My goal is to give the css properties each of the cloned elements, but I stuck in here w/o no clues.

Full Code:

```js
'use strict';
(function ($, window, undefined) {
  $.fn.cardSlider = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      const $el = $(this);
      var thatCards = new Card($el, options);
          thatCards.scrolling($el);
    })
  }
  class Card {
    constructor($el) {
      this.$el = $el; // 0
      this.myCards = this.$el.find('a'); // 1
      this.myCount = 1; // 2
      this.myLength = this.myCards.length; // 3
      this.firstClone = this.myCards.first().before(this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned')); // 4 this makes the clone.
      this.lastClone = this.myCards.last().after(this.myCards.first().clone().addClass('cloned'));
    }
    scrolling($el) {
      console.log(this.firstClone); 
      this.firstClone.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-1) + "%)"; // Browser fires an error. Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined
      this.firstClone.css({
        paddingBottom: 200 + 'px'
      }); // An example for proving that the css property doesn't refer to the real clone.
      for (var i = 0; i < this.myLength; i++) {
        this.myCards[i].style.transform = "translateX(" + Math.pow(2, i) + "%)";
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
$('.outer').cardSlider();
```

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.film {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 90%;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 74%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.images:first-child, .images:last-child {
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="film">
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*I tested this code in Codepen and here but both didn't work. You probably have to make the new files to test this.

Comment: Is there any reason you have structured your code like that? Using the `init` array instead of individual variables? I find it quite hard to read.

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I wanted to group up and separated it for looking better and more clearer, but it seems not anymore.

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong. `myCards.first().before()` doesn't modify `myCards`.

Comment: If you want to keep them grouped, use an object. Then you can write `this.init.holder`, `this.init.cards`, etc. This is much easier to understand than magic numbers like `this.init[1]`.

Comment: @l3lue The problem you are introducing with this grouping strategy is called "magic values". When you are talking about `init[4]`, nobody knows what you mean by that. The number 4 is arbitrary. You should give your variables names that speak for themselves (which you already did when you declared them).

Comment: @TheBlackIPs I changed the code for more readable.

Comment: @Barmar If I use the object, then I can't do like this: `const init = { myHolder: $el, myCards: myHolder.find('a') }` it fires `myHolder` is undefined. That's why I was using the array.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what this is supposed to do, and what the problem is. You're not giving the `translateX` property to either of the cloned elements, you're only giving the property to the elements in `this.myCards`.

Comment: Maybe you need to update `this.myCards` after you add the clones?

Comment: @Barmar I added the line, in the code, `this.firstClone.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-1) + "%)";` This fires an error that firstClone is undefined. Sorry about the code isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite messy, but I think one problem you have is that you assign the wrong element to `firstClone` and `lastClone`. You propably want those variables to be references to the new clones, but that's not what your code does.

**Let's look at this line:**

`this.firstClone = this.myCards.first().before(this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned'));`

- First, you clone the last card and add the class `cloned` (`this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned')`)
- Then, you pass that clone to the function `before` of the first card (`this.myCards.first().before(...)`)
- Finally, you assign whatever the function `before` returns to the variable `this.firstClone`

The problem is that the expression `a.before(b)` inserts `b` before `a` and then **returns `a`**. What you want to save, though, is a reference to `b`, not `a`.

You have to use the function `insertBefore` instead. It does exactly the same as `before`, but the other way around: `b.insertBefore(a)` also inserts `b` before `a`, but this **returns `b`**.

(See the difference here: https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-before-and-insertbefore-example/)

So the line we looked at should be:

`this.firstClone = this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned').insertBefore(this.myCards.first());`

This way, your variable `this.firstClone` holds a reference to the newly created clone and not the (previously) first element. The same holds for the line after that:

`this.lastClone = this.myCards.first().clone().addClass('cloned').insertAfter(this.myCards.last());`

I hope this solves your problem.

**Used in context:**

```js
'use strict';
(function ($, window, undefined) {
  $.fn.cardSlider = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      const $el = $(this);
      var thatCards = new Card($el, options);
          thatCards.scrolling($el);
    })
  }
  class Card {
    constructor($el) {
      this.$el = $el; // 0
      this.myCards = this.$el.find('a'); // 1
      this.myCount = 1; // 2
      this.myLength = this.myCards.length; // 3
      this.firstClone = this.myCards.last().clone().addClass('cloned').insertBefore(this.myCards.first()); // 4 this makes the clone.
      this.lastClone = this.myCards.first().clone().addClass('cloned').insertAfter(this.myCards.last());
    }
    scrolling($el) {
      console.log(this.myCards[1]); // Both refers the same element
      this.firstClone.css({
        paddingBottom: 200 + 'px'
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < this.myLength; i++) {
        this.myCards[i].style.transform = "translateX(" + Math.pow(2, i) + "%)";
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
$('.outer').cardSlider();
```

```css
.outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.film {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 90%;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 74%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.images:first-child, .images:last-child {
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="film">
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
        <a class="images" href="#" draggable="false"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.firstClone` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. But `style` is a DOM property. In jQuery you use the `.css()` function to add styles, so it should be:

```
this.firstClone.css("transform", "translateX(-1%)");
```

or you can put it as part of the following:

```
  this.firstClone.css({
    paddingBottom: 200 + 'px',
    transform: "translateX(-1%)"
  });
```

Your code works in the `for` loop because when you index a jQuery collection, it returns the corresponding DOM element (to get the jQuery object, you use `.eq(i)`). So you could also write the above as:

```
this.firstClone[0].style.transform = "translateX(-1%)";
```

Comment: I've tried to those ways before I asked the question but none of those didn't work. But still thank you for answering.

Comment: I see that the other question addressed a different problem, where you're not setting `firstClone` and `lastClone` as you intended.